# Prevent JavaScript actions on Ember.js components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to prevent JavaScript actions on my ember component like `hover, click, double click, focus, etc.`.

Simple way is to define this actions for the component and do `event.preventDefault()` and `return false`;

Is there any other way by which I can achieve the same ? I tried using CSS for this `pointer-events : none` which is fine for UI experience. But when I go to console, I see that I can still invoke click actions on my component div. So, is there any way by which I can prevent these actions all at once maybe during `init` of the component ?

Comment: I am doing this on a certain condition, I want to disable mouse actions on my component. I only want it for viewing purposes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I ended up with this implementation. Not ideal but works !

```
    //component.js

    isDisabled : false // flag to decide disabling
    listOfSupportedBrowserEvents : ['click', 'focusOut', 'mouseEnter', 'mouseLeave'],

    // mixin.js

    updateEventHandlersOnDidInsertElement: function(){
        if(this.get('isDisabled')) {
                    this.get('listOfSupportedBrowserEvents').forEach(function(eventName) {
                        this.$().on(eventName, Ember.run.bind(this, this._disableBrowserEvents));
                    }.bind(this));
                }
            }.on('didInsertElement'),

    updateEventHandlersOnWillDestroyElement: function(){
         if(this.get('isDisabled')) {
                    this.get('listOfSupportedBrowserEvents').forEach(function(eventName) {
                        this.$().off(eventName, Ember.run.bind(this, this._disableBrowserEvents));
                    }.bind(this));
                }
            }.on('willDestroyElement'),

    _disableBrowserEvents : function() {
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

So, I have on occasion made things readonly in Ember with a component by using the jquery [blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin

```
export function blockElement(selector, shouldBlock){
    $(selector).unblock();
    if(shouldBlock){
        $(selector).block({message: null, overlayCSS:  {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity:         0.01,
            cursor:          'not-allowed'
        }});
    }
}
```

This creates an overlay and prevents any user interaction. In your case, selector would be the components id, which you can get via `this.elementId` from your component. To me, this approach works way better than trying to rejigger all of my UI into readonly mode